# How is __dir__ implemented exactly, and how should I know it?

Tags: python, python-internals

So I'm trying to know the details of `dir()` function. First I looked at the implementation of it:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e76daebc0c8afa3981a4c5a8b54537f756e805de/Objects/object.c#L1450-L1477

```c
/* Helper for PyObject_Dir: object introspection. */
static PyObject *
_dir_object(PyObject *obj)
{
    PyObject *result, *sorted;
    PyObject *dirfunc = _PyObject_LookupSpecial(obj, &PyId___dir__);

    assert(obj);
    if (dirfunc == NULL) {
        if (!PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "object does not provide __dir__");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* use __dir__ */
    result = _PyObject_CallNoArg(dirfunc);
    Py_DECREF(dirfunc);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    /* return sorted(result) */
    sorted = PySequence_List(result);
    Py_DECREF(result);
    if (sorted == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (PyList_Sort(sorted)) {
        Py_DECREF(sorted);
        return NULL;
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

And found that the `_dir_object` function doesn't do any work itself, but invokes the `__dir__` method of the introspected object.

```python
>>> def test(): pass
>>> test.__dir__
<built-in method __dir__ of function object at 0x10ee57ae8>
```

So how to know the implementation of it?

Comment: On Python 3.6 I do get `__dir__` among the members listed. I guess you're testing on an older version which didn't always have it defined. You should test on a version matching the code you're examining.

Comment: @interjay: right, in Python 2, the `__getattribute__` method for functions doesn't consider the type when looking up attributes directly on the function object.

Comment: You appear to be using Python 2 to test, but are looking at the Python 3 source code. Know that they differ materially!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__dir__` is a *special method*, so looked up on the type, at least in Python 3:

```
>>> type(test)
<class 'function'>
>>> '__dir__' in dir(type(test))
True
>>> type(test).__dir__
<method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
>>> dir(test) == sorted(type(test).__dir__(test))
True
```

See the [*Special method lookup* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) of the datamodel:

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

This is exactly what the `_PyObject_LookupSpecial()` function does, see [the `typeobject.c` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1de60155d5d01be2924e72fb68dd13d4fd00acd7/Objects/typeobject.c#L1584-L1613):

```c
res = _PyType_LookupId(Py_TYPE(self), attrid);
```

The `Py_TYPE()` call there is the important part, `__dir__` is looked up on the *type*.

The `__dir__` method is implemented on the `object` type and inherited by the function type, so the implementation is in the [`object_dir()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L4469-L4514).

For Python 2, the [`dir()` implementation is more elaborate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Objects/object.c#L1908-L1961), and actually also delegates to other functions! For function objects, it delegates to the [`_generic_dir()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Objects/object.c#L1852-L1906). This function consults the `__dict__` of the type:

```c
/* Merge in attrs reachable from its class. */
itsclass = PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "__class__");
if (itsclass == NULL)
    /* XXX(tomer): Perhaps fall back to obj->ob_type if no
                   __class__ exists? */
    PyErr_Clear();
else {
    if (merge_class_dict(dict, itsclass) != 0)
        goto error;
}
```

where [`merge_class_dict()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.14/Objects/object.c#L1680-L1737) recursively incorporates the class hierarchy attributes into the final result.

Comment: `test.__dir__` should work even if `__dir__` is defined on the type. I think OP is testing on an old Python version.

Comment: What wouldn't work is that if you define `__dir__` on a specific instance, it wouldn't be called by `dir`. But `test.__dir__` should work in any case because it looks up in the type after trying the instance..

Comment: I think @MartijnPieters has misunderstood @interjay. I think the implication is that `assert hasattr(type(obj), "__dir__")` implies `assert hasattr(obj, "__dir__")`. And is refering to the attribute error that OP has mentioned.

Comment: @Dunes: Right, yes, in Python 3.6 `test.__dir__` works because it is found on `type(test)`.

Comment: It seems like OP is running 2.7 or earlier where even `type(test).__dir__` results in an attribute error.

Comment: Sorry I was running 2.7. In 3.6 test.__dir__ returns a function object. Will edit question.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking at is from a recent Python version, but you're testing on an old version.

In the new version, an implementation `__dir__` is automatically provided on all types.

In the old version, objects do not have `__dir__` unless it is manually provided. The implementation then takes this into account in `_dir_object`. This is from Python 2.7:

```
if (dirfunc == NULL) {
    /* use default implementation */
    if (PyModule_Check(obj))
        result = _specialized_dir_module(obj);
    else if (PyType_Check(obj) || PyClass_Check(obj))
        result = _specialized_dir_type(obj);
    else
        result = _generic_dir(obj);
}
```

For the implementation of `object.__dir__` in Python 3, see [`object___dir___impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/07ca9afaa8768b44baf816b4998d209ed3e0088f/Objects/typeobject.c#L4653) in Objects/typeobject.c.

Comment: Old vs new meaning 2.x vs 3.x?

Comment: @Piinthesky I don't know if the new mechanism was added in 3.0 or later, but it seems likely that it's a 3.0 change.